How can I find an invertible function to flatten a probability distribution function into a uniform distribution?
Let us assume that I have a Probability Density Function $t \to f(t)$, s.t. $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)d\tau = 1$$ and it is very "long-tailed".
What I seek is given an estimate of $f$ - for example a sampled histogram - some way to estimate or calculate an invertible function $g$, so that g(f(t)) will be uniformly distributed on [0,1] or actually on [-1,1], but they are so easy to convert between that it is of minor importance.
The goal being that I seek a practical and systematic way of expressing quantization of measurable data. If I can represent the couple $(g,\{g(\hat f)\})$, $\{\hat f\}$ being a set of samples in a computer and g being invertible then quantization will be much easier.
My intuition tells me that what I am looking for in some sense is equivalent to find the inverse function to the cumulative density function. As the integral of the uniform distribution is the identity.

Own work : I suppose I could formulate a variational optimization problem given for example the squared Kullback-Leibler measure. $$\min_g |D_{KL}(g(f(t)),u(t))|^2$$
Or a more direct approach could be to just go for the squared difference integral $\min_g \int |g(f(t))-u(t)|^2 dt$ or in a practical setting to build a histogram and calculate the summed square differences over the bins.

Is $g$ required to be left-invertible? Right-invertible? Both? Seems like what you are looking for is equivalent to estimating the quantiles of the distribution.

What you are looking for seems to be exactly probability integral transform, i.e. passing the observed values through a suitably smoothed (to get invertibility) empirical CDF will do the trick. See e.g. Fernholz 1991 for a theoretically appealing construction, but I'd expect many variants to work OK with enough data, including a piecewuse linear interpolation of the empirical CDF.
All results on estimating CDF from data (e.g. confidence bounds for CDFs) directly apply to e.g. let you get the uncertainty of the transformation.
